# Using OAuth with Google thru the Python library requests-oauthlib throws the exception MissingCodeError

Tags: python, oauth, google-oauth, python-requests

I'm using the Python library [requests-oauthlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib) in order to create an app which can use OAuth with some main providers (Google, Dropbox, Facebook, Twitter).
The example code provided [here](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/google.html) gives me an exception:

```
raise MissingCodeError("Missing code parameter in response.")
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MissingCodeError: Missing code parameter in response.
```

The problem is not in the web application client that I created with the Google API console, because I wrote another piece of code doing the same thing but using the Python library google-api-python-client and it works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake!

I got confused because using:

```
google.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret, authorization_response=redirect_response)
```

it is required that redirect_response is a full url.
While using:

```
google.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret,
... code=redirect_response)
```

it is required that redirect_response is only the code replied by Google.

Comment: I am actually experiencing the same error... Can you share your solution to this? This is the example I followed: http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/github.html

Comment: It was a long time ago and I don't remember all details. But I guess that redirect_response is something like `http://googlewhatever.../?code=mycode`. The first piece of code written in the answer will work if `redirect_response='http://googlewhatever.../?code=mycode'`. While the second piece of code will work if `redirect_response='mycode'`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Which OAUTH library did you use eventually?

Comment: I used requests-oauthlib. While for another Django project I used django-allauth.